# How to add backbutton functionality to app

Tags: java

I'm trying to add a backbutton functionality to my app.

However when I try to add the id of the backButton like so,

```
 Button back = findViewById(R.id.backButton);
        back.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener()
            {
               @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                  finish();
                 }
             }
```

it just says the symbol for it is missing.

I'm guessing and xml reference to the button is not present, where can I add it. Also the navigation bar (the back and home button and such) is not showing in the bottom of the app in android studio, is there a way to enable that?

Comment: add the id to the xml where you inflated to.

Comment: @JohnJoe wouldn't I need the navigation bar to do that?

Comment: you mean the bottom navigation bar?

Comment: yes that's what I meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you looking is call [BottomNavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView).

You should place the id in `onNavigationItemSelected`.

**MainActivty**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView mTextMessage;

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_home);
                    return true;
                case R.id.back:
                    finish();
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        mTextMessage = findViewById(R.id.message);
        navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
    }  
}
```

**activity_main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:text="@string/title_home"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Create an xml file under menu folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_home" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:icon="@drawable/back"
        android:title="@string/title_dashboard" />

</menu>
```